Generate dynamic tasks with Airflow with .expand
I have the a DAG with the following structure:
with DAG(
    # configs go here
) as dag:
    
    def get_intervals()
        
        # logic to retrieve some data from CloudSQL
        
        return intervals # intervals looks like: [['0'], ['10'], ['50'], ['100']]
        
    def extract_data(table_name, date, interval, **context):
    
        query = f"SELECT * FROM {table_name} WHERE my_date = {date} AND my_interval = {interval}"
        
        # logic to extract from CloudSQL into GCS / works fine with hardcoded parameters
        
    get_intervals_task = PythonOperator(
        task_id='task_1',
        python_callable=get_intervals
    )
    
    extract_data_task = PythonOperator.partial(
        task_id='task_2',
        python_callable=extract_data,
        op_kwargs={
            'table_name': 'my_table',
            'date': '2023-01-01'}
    ).expand(op_args=get_intervals_task.output)
    
    get_intervals_task >> extract_data_task

I'm getting two errors:
TypeError: extract_data missing 1 required positional argument: 'interval'

and
ValueError: The key 'table_name' in args is a part of kwargs and therefore reserved.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. My expectations are that the op_kwargs provided should be kept the same for each generated task while the list provided in expand to be used to generate the dynamic tasks.
Any help is appreciated.

Which version of Airflow are you running ? Information between tasks is usually conveyed using XComs and since v2.0 you can use TaskFlow too.

The first error is because you have defined a required parameter in extract_data_task as interval and your op_kwargs is missing that definition. For other try other param name like db_table_name
